# Pronunciation of "AUCTeX"

Tags: auctex

I'd like to give a tutorial on AUCTeX to my colleagues but it occurs to me that I've never heard the name of this package pronounced.  It seems the first three letters could be pronounced individually (/ɛɪ juː siː/) or as a word (maybe /aːk/ or /ɔːk/).  I'm not looking to poll StackExchange users on their preferred pronunciation but rather to ask whether there is an "official" one favoured by the primary authors.  I didn't find anything in the package documentation but perhaps someone here has heard the authors speak the name at a conference presentation or lecture.

Comment: I've always assumed that it's a word play on `octet`, 8 bits, computers bla bla.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AUCTEX tells what I knew: "Aalborg University Center". So "ah you see" might be the "correct" pronunciation.

Comment: I always say Ay you see, the way I would normally pronounce the three letters separately, although as @egreg says the A is really an Å so if your Danish pronunciation is up to that.....

Comment: If you want to contact the primary authors, I think the [AUCTeX contact page](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/contact.html) is the best place to look. Here on TeX.SX, your question seems off topic.

Comment: @StephanLehmke I don't think this question is off-topic, as it is about "Related software and tools, BibTeX, MakeIndex, Lyx, etc." ([faq#questions]). There may better places to ask this, though, yes.

Comment: The OP is explicitly *not* asking for opinions from the TeX.SX community, but for an answer from the original authors. I think it is more than improbable that @davidkastrup, for instance, is going to answer here, while the probability is much higher on the contact page directly dedicated to that.

Comment: How odd.  There were similar questions here asking about official pronunciations ("What is the correct pronunciation of TeX and LaTeX?" and "How do I pronounce “TikZ”?") after which I patterned this question.  They attracted high ratings, lots of comments, and weren't closed for being off-topic.  If there's any way I could reword my question to bring it more in line with those, please let me know.

Comment: If the A in AucTeX should be pronounced as the Å in Ålborg, the A would be pronounced as the sound of the o in the beginning of the word "order".